# SQL запрос на выборку

Tags: выборка, mysql

Здравствуйте, возникла такая проблема.

Есть таблица `sms` (`id`, `number`, `text`). Из этой таблицы нужно выбрать все строки, но есть ограничение на столбец `number`, должно выбираться не больше 10 записей одного номера. Т.е. все телефоны, но ограничение в каждый номер не больше 10 строк. Какой запрос должен быть?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю можно придумать какой-то такой хитрый запрос, но если задача разовая (или выполняется нечасто, например какая-то ежесуточная аналитика) то можно схалтурить и сделать в несколько запросов (выбрать все номера `SELECT DISTINCT number FROM sms;` (кажется так) потом проэтерироваться по этому списку и сделать `SELECT * FROM sms WHERE number=$number LIMIT 10;`).

Для не частых запросов сойдёт.

Comment: Так и сделано на текущий момент, но хотелось бы решение в один запрос.

Comment: Не факт что оно будет быстрее или читабельнее.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov удалил свой ответ с решением задача в один вопрос, так-как эксперимент показал что он работает значительно медленнее тупого решения (материалы проведённого мной эксперимента http://pastebin.mozilla.org/5280923, зря я что-ли корячился).

Так-что если кто-то не предложит другой способ сделать это в один запрос то я рекомендую оставить всё как есть (решение в несколько запросов) и искать другие места для оптимизации (например переиспользовать подключения к БД)

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).